# Tell latex to print bibliography exactly as it is

Tags: biber, zotero

I use Zotero for my literature and the following package to include it in my thesis:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, natbib, style=trad-abbrv, maxbibnames=5, minbibnames=5, giveninits=true,
    style=apa
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}
```

This generally works pretty well, only that some titles, that are capitalized are written in small letters when I print my bibliography. How can I tell Latex to just print it as it is in Zotero?

[image]

Note that in the picture below, Edgerton (1997) is fine, whereas titles in German, that need to be capitalized are misspelled.

[image]

Comment: add the langid field to the german entries.

Comment: Since the .bib file is generated automatically from Zotero I can acces it or at least I dont know how

Comment: you can add fields also on the fly in the document, see the biblatex documentation. You can also disable sentence casing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, natbib, style=trad-abbrv, maxbibnames=5, minbibnames=5, giveninits=true,
    style=apa
]{biblatex}
```

is a bit confusing, since it uses `style` twice. The second `style` wins, so you end up loading `style=apa,`. (Note that if you want real APA style, you should not be adding options such as `maxbibnames=5, minbibnames=5, giveninits=true,`, `style=apa,` already gives you the best APA style available in `biblatex` at the moment, additional options may in fact make the output deviate from APA style.)

APA style wants certain titles formatted in "sentence case", which means that all letters except the first are converted to lower case. This is what you are seeing here.

Sentence casing does not make sense for German titles like the example entry you show and in fact `biblatex` will not apply sentence casing for German works (at least with styles that use the recommended `\MakeSentenceCase*` over  `\MakeSentenceCase`). You just need a way to tell `biblatex` that your work is in German. `biblatex` 'guesses' the language as follows.

- If a `langid` field is present, the language is taken from that field.
- If `langid` is not present, `biblatex` will assume the entry is in the (currently active) document language.

In the example you want to add

```
langid = {ngerman},
```

to the entry `edenhofer_klimapolitik_2019`. Then `biblatex` knows that your entry should not get sentence casing.

If your entire document is in German, it should be enough to load `babel`/`polyglossia` with the appropriate options and `biblatex` will guess the right language. If you plan on writing documents in different languages, it is definitely recommended to make use of the `langid` field.

If I understand correctly, Zotero normally maps its *language* field to `langid`. So if you put `de` into the *language* field, you should get the desired output.

If you don't want sentence casing it all, you can usually disable it with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}
```

and in case of `biblatex-apa` with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
```

---

While the above is written with `style=apa,` in mind, you would have been able to reproduce a similar effect with `style=trad-abbrv,`, since the `biblatex-trad` styles also apply sentence case. The `biblatex` standard styles don't sentence case by default, so there you wouldn't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a language field in Zotero entries. Setting it to de (for deutsch) for the german entries should help.
[A Zotero official answer to a related question.](https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/preventing_title_casing_for_non-english_titles)